# Using XPath to find the value of an attribute in a node based on another attribute in the same node?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I have an xml document that is constructed pretty poorly-- instead of child nodes, the items have multiple attributes.

For Example:

```
<makes>
<option make="FORD" year_start="1950" year_end="2009" />
<option make="CHEVROLET" year_start="1965" year_end="2009" />
...
</makes>
```

I'm trying to use XPath to select the value of the other attributes for all nodes that match a certain attribute. I'm populating 3 asp drop down menus with values from 2 xml documents based on a previous selection. I'm using .net/c#

For Example:
*for all option nodes with a make attribute that has the value x, find the value of year_start.*

I tried something like this:

```
  yearListData.XPath = string.Format("/makes/option[@year_start] and [@make={0}]", make);
```

where make = the previous selection. Obviously, it didn't work.

is there a way using XPath to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
/makes/option[@year_start and @make="FORD"]/@year_start
```

You can combine with AND/OR conditions inside the `[` and `]`, then ask for the attribute.

Comment: The @year_start in the predicate is probably overkill, since it can't return something that doesn't exist, but it will give the right answer.

Comment: I left it in there to drive home the point that expressions can be combined in the predicate.

Comment: this worked for me, but I'm still having issues; can you recommend a good .net/c# & xml resource?

Answer (score 1):

```
/makes/option[@make='FORD']/@year_start
```

...will get you all year_start attributes under options where the make is "FORD". Attributes are generally preferable to child elements if there's a 1-to-1 relationship--they don't require a verbose closing tag.

You might also consider linq to XML.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work, but I think you could accomplish that with something like:

```
string.Format("/makes/option[@make={0}]//@year_start",make);
```